# Fetch data express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Right now I am getting data from mysql in `res.send` but if I want to display two different records in different position (two different `<ul>`) then how can I do this?

Here is my code

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM test',
                 function (err, rows, fields) {
                     if (err) throw err
                     var id =rows[0].number;
                     if (id != req.body.id) {
                         res.send("wrong accept");
                     } else {
                         var test = rows;
                         var length = Object.keys(rows).length;
                         const numberList = rows.map(row => row.number)
                         const numberLists = rows.map(row => row.test)
                         res.send({ number: numberList, text: numberLists })
                     }  
                 })
```

Comment: Maybe send an Array instead of an Object?

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're trying to do, you want to show 2 different `<ul>` elements for what?

Comment: For that I need to know Which templating engine are you using?